# Most light-weight way to retrieve content of a webpage in R?

Tags: r

I'm aware of rvest's `xml2::read_html()`, which can be provided with a URL to retrieve the contents of the webpage.

What is the lightest-weight way to retrieve the contents of a webpage (i.e. preferably without any packages; i.e. using just base R)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `download.file` function in the utils package (automatically installed and loaded) will download a page for you.  It will not do any parsing, just save it to a file on the local computer.

A combination of `readLines` and `url` (both in the base package) will read a webpage into a vector of character strings for you (again no parsing).